# Is there a three.js function to simulate camera movement?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two models in my scene. I can click a button to teleport the camera to different spaces within the scene with this code:

```
camera.position.set(0, 100, -350); //sets initial camera orbit rotation
controls.target.set(0, 0, 0); //sets orbit location in world
```

Is there a three.js function to simulate camera movement between points instead?

Comment: Use tween.js or GSAP libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use an animation library like `tween.js` to solve this issue. The internal animation system of `three.js` could also be used but it's low-level API is more intended for asset loaders.

Check out the following example made with `tween.js`. Check out how the camera position is animated over two seconds and how the `onUpdate()` callback is used to focus the camera on the mesh.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;
    
    var target = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 1 );
    
    new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position )
      .to( { x: target.x, y: target.y, z: target.z }, 2000 )
      .onUpdate( () => { camera.lookAt( scene.position ); } )
      .start();

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
    TWEEN.update();
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.3.5/Tween.js"></script>
```